# Docker not able to access folder in windows-10 enterprise

Tags: docker

**Setup:**

- Docker community edition 18.03.0-ce-win59 (16762)
- Windows 10 enterprise edition.

When I am trying to share the C drive in docker settings, it is asking to provide the windows credential. When I am entering the correct username and password, the system is rejecting the request and mentioning invalid.

[image]

Comment: Please add your image

Comment: Are you sure your credentials are ok, that the user "bala" has enough privileges to do this (your windows says no...)

Comment: Please click on the text "enter image description here" to find the image.

Credentials are correct, just for example I have provided that username.